# I'm having troubles with setting titles in toolbar using fragments in tabLayoyt (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have been struggling with this issue for about a week now...

The thing is, that im having alot of trouble to set the title in toolbar depending of which tab is active ?!

I have my mainActivity, in which I have a TabLayout and a Viewpager, that inflates 3 different fragments (tabs)

Here's my MainActivy :

```
package stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Activities;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import at.markushi.ui.CircleButton;
import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Adapters.TabFragmentAdapter;
import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public EditText editTextSearchTitle;
    public String searchTitle;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    final Context context = this;

    private static final String LOG_TAG_REFRESH = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String LOG_TAG_CAST = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffc800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#d2d4d2"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                //tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#d2d4d2"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Launches the Search DialogFragment
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

                dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_search);

                editTextSearchTitle = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextSearchTitle);

                // Performs the search
                Button dialogBtnSearch = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.searchBtnOk);
                dialogBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                // Closes the Dialog
                Button dialogBtnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.searchBtnCancel);
                dialogBtnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                // Handles Voice Search
                CircleButton speakButton = (CircleButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.searchBtnSpeak);
                speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startVoiceRecognition();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        //tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        //tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        //tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);

        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab1.setIcon(R.color.tab1_selector);
        tab1.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffc800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab2.setIcon(R.color.tab2_selector);
        tab2.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#d2d4d2"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
        tab3.setIcon(R.color.tab3_selector);
        tab3.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#d2d4d2"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    }

    private void startVoiceRecognition() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

        //since you only want one, only request 1
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_main) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_main:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tab1) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_tab1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tab2) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_tab2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tab3) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_tab3:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_help:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my FragmentAdapter :

```
package stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Fragments.Tabs.Tab1;
import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Fragments.Tabs.Tab2;
import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Fragments.Tabs.Tab3;

/**
 * Created by Stefan on 24-07-2016.
 */
public class TabFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Context context;

    public TabFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {

        super(supportFragmentManager);
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                return new Tab1();

            case 1:
                return new Tab2();

            case 2:
                return new Tab3();

            // In order to add extra tab's, just add extra case here

        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // NOTICE!! Specify the number of above case's here, in order to show ALL tabs
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //If you want title's on the tabs, then just remove the outcommenting
        /*
        // Setting the titles on tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return context.getString(R.string.tab_title_tab1);

            case 1:
                return context.getString(R.string.tab_title_tab2);

            case 2:
                return context.getString(R.string.tab_title_tab3);
        }
        */
        return null;
    }
}
```

And one the Fragment's (the 3 of them are the same!!)

```
package stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.Fragments.Tabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import stefankorfitz.slidingtabdemo.R;

/**
 * Created by Stefan on 24-07-2016.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    View view;
    TextView action_bar_title;

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;

    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = Tab1.class.getSimpleName();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //android.app.ActionBar actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        //actionbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_tab1));
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1,
                container, false);

        //int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        //action_bar_title = (TextView) action_bar_title.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        //action_bar_title.setText(R.string.title_guide_1_xx);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.green, R.color.orange, R.color.red);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Refresh swipe started...");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toast_refreshing_content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                // Updates the content of Tab1 using SwipeRefresh
                // TODO : Implement code here

                // Turns OFF the Refresh-Ring
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 1000);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Refresh swipe finished!");
    }
}
```

Notice! The main challenge I have, is that all the solutions i've tried so far, only sets the same title in Tab1 + Tab2... And then when I swipe all the over to Tab3, it sets the correct Title for Tab3, but it stays there when I swipe back to Tab2 and then when I get all the way back to Tab1 it then shows the Title of Tab2 ?!

I WOULD BE SO SO HAPPY, IF ANYONE COULD HELP ME OUT HERE...

In case of code is missing from the example to cast some light of the problem ?! Then pls let me know, and I will upload some more examples :-)

Thank you guy's in advance...

Comment: Where are you setting the title ?

Comment: The title comes from strings.xml res!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setOnTabSelectedListener, try something like this:

```
@Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffc800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
               switch (tab.getPosition()){
                  case 0:
                     getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title1");
                   break;
                  case 1:
                         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title2");
                      break;
                  case 2:
                         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title3");
                      break;
                      }
                }
```

Comment: Wow!! This solution is the closest i've come so far !! Only small bug is : It doesn't set the title at first on Tab1 - But after the first swipe, it then works perfectly :-)

Comment: Any thoughts on that !?

Comment: For now, i just used that R.string.tab_title_1 in the label-attribute in my manifest file on the MainActivity :-)

Comment: Perhaps it is kind of a bad practice ?! But untill I find a better way, then this has to do... ;-)

Comment: Yes you can use the default title for the title1, I think the first time the onTabSelected is not trigered as the first page is show by default

Comment: Or in your onCreate method you can directly set the getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title1");

Comment: Anyway!... Thank you SO much for your help! That was awesome man ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a common function at MainActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



 public static void settitle(String title){

        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }
```

Now call below method from each fragment where you want to set title.

```
MainActivity.settitle(getString(R.string.dashboard));
```

OR
Add title like below:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

               getSupportActionBar("title1");

            case 1:
              getSupportActionBar("title2");

            case 2:
               getSupportActionBar("title3");


        }
        return null;

    }
```

But i suggested First with comment class.